# RecyclerView Highlight Item & CAB

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am using [TwoWayView Library](https://github.com/lucasr/twoway-view) in my application for an easy to use RecyclerView with Onclick support, however it does not support drawable state or contextual actionbar. Can anyone help me add support for this?

Comment: The creator of the library got back to me and provided official documentation [here](https://plus.google.com/117146991527827534089/posts/g9r83QYys2y) for it.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve this by setting a state drawable as the background for your `ViewHolder`'s `itemView`, and using `TwoWayView.setSelected(isSelected)`.

To hook it up to a CAB, see [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#CAB).